# Solving design issues in XML?

Tags: android, xml

When im designing my android app im using XML and for this app im using the Relative layout but when i put the buttons on my screen with the png background i made its just looking bad.. the buttons are not put equaly like they should..
Look at this picture:

[image: Picture of my design]

How would i solve so the pluss buttons and percent and comma and equal button will be placed right instead of looking all that weird?

If you are intrested to see my XML code here is an link for pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/gpxnPT4P

Comment: Why you don't use GridLayout?

Comment: Cus when i asked here on stack overflow for advice how to put the buttons next to each other they said relative would be best for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to check the `android:layout_...` of every item that is showing wrong. For example, the declaration for the number 5 button is:

```
<Button android:background="@drawable/number5" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:id="@+id/number5" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/number8" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/divided"></Button>
```

If you look closely the [`android:layout_alignLeft`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignLeft) declaration is pointing to de divide button  (`@+id/divided`) that is far away. There is a similar situation with the button for number 6.

Try this declaration for number 5 button:

```
<Button android:background="@drawable/number5" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:id="@+id/number5" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/number8" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/number4"></Button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I misunderstand the meaning of "alignLeft". Try changing the `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/number4"` for `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/number4"`. [This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) may help you.